# error in importing package net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient

Tags: corda

When executing a seperate client app it will show the following error:

```
Error:(33, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: CordaRPCClient error in importing package net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient
```

My client code details are given below.Copied and Imported the corda-app jar after running gradlew.bat buildnodes

```
package com.template

import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient
import net.corda.core.messaging.startFlow
import net.corda.core.utilities.NetworkHostAndPort.Companion.parse
import net.corda.core.utilities.loggerFor
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import com.template.flows.IOUFlow
import net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name
import net.corda.core.utilities.getOrThrow

fun main(args: Array<String>) = Client().main(args)
private class Client {
    companion object {
        val logger = loggerFor<Client>()
    }

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        require(args.size == 3) { "Usage: Client <node address> <rpc username> <rpc password>" }
        val nodeAddress = parse(args[0])
        val rpcUsername = args[1]
        val rpcPassword = args[2]
        val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)
        //val proxy = client.start(rpcUsername, rpcPassword).proxy
        val connection = client.start(rpcUsername, rpcPassword)
        val cordaRPCOperations = connection.proxy

        val nodes = cordaRPCOperations.networkMapSnapshot()
        logger.info("{}", nodes)
        val x500Name = CordaX500Name.parse("O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US")

        val partyf = cordaRPCOperations.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(x500Name)

        logger.info(cordaRPCOperations.currentNodeTime().toString())


    }
}
```

Comment: Could be any number of things. I would start by checking your gradle dependencies, and refreshing/re-running gradle import to see if this yields any unexpected results.

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html

Comment: Copied and Imported the corda-app jar after running gradlew.bat buildnodes.When compiling client its shows CordaRPCClient error in importing package net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.Is it mandatory to include jar file info in gradle build file

Comment: please check your corda-app jar has it or not .It must be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your corda-rpc client or rpc client must have the below dependency :

```
cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
```